# Repeat each line multiple times and add ascending numbers

Tags: linux, awk, text, sed, wget

Would like to have each line in a file repeated a fixed number of times and add ascending numbers, like this:

I have

```
wwx.domain.com/pageA/?page=1
wwx.domain.com/pageB/?page=1
wwx.domain.com/pageC/?page=1
```

I want

```
wwx.domain.com/pageA/?page=1
wwx.domain.com/pageA/?page=2
wwx.domain.com/pageA/?page=3
wwx.domain.com/pageB/?page=1
wwx.domain.com/pageB/?page=2
wwx.domain.com/pageB/?page=3
wwx.domain.com/pageC/?page=1
wwx.domain.com/pageC/?page=2
wwx.domain.com/pageC/?page=3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: On stack exchange sites it's strongly encouraged to share what approach you
have tried so far (preferably in the form of some code, if applicable). Many
users don't want to spend their time simply doing people's coding tasks for
them, but all users are happy to _help_ you solve a problem! (not my downvote
btw, but I'm sure this is likely the reason someone else downvoted your
question). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ sub(/.$/,""); for(i=1; i<4; i++) print $0 i }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Explanation: Remove the last character from the input line, and in a loop print the (modified) input line followed by the loop index.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;:a;s/[^\n]*/&/3;t;x;s/(.*=)(.*)/echo "\1$((\2+1))"/e;x;G;ta' file
```

While the pattern space contains less than n (in this case 3) lines, append the current line, incrementing the last field by 1.

The solution uses the hold space to keep the last incremented line and shell arithmetic to increment the last field of the line.